AckermannSteering: What is the meaning of sub_topic
Here is a snippet from the Gazebo Harmonic, AckermannSteering documentation:
<topic>: Custom topic that this system will subscribe to in order to receive command messages. This element is optional, and the default value is /model/{name_of_model}/cmd_vel or when steering_only is true /model/{name_of_model}/steer_angle.
<sub_topic>: Custom sub_topic that this system will subscribe to in order to receive command messages. This element is optional, and creates a topic /model/{name_of_model}/{sub_topic}
I don't really get the meaning of <sub_topic> and I tried a coule of things:

If I don't specify either, I have the topic /model/${robot_name}/cmd_vel.
If I specify only topic, I have the topic /${specified_topic_name}
If I specify only sub_topic, I have the topic /model/${robot_name}/${specified_sub_topic_name}.
If I specify topic and sub_topic, I have the topic /${specified_topic_name}.

Point 1 is obvious and the result is as I expected.
The result in Point 2 is also as expected.
The result in Point 3 is kind of what I expexted.
According to Point 4, topic is "dominating" sub_topic (kind of), which is not really confusing but makes the whole existence of sub_topic meaningless...
Both of the topics are of the same type, i.e. gz.msgs.Twist (checked with gz topic --info -t {topic_name}).
In conclusion, I don't really get the meaning of sub_topic.
What could be a usecase?
My apologies if this is not really technically relevant, but it makes me curious and I want to set every parameter correctly with the right purpose.

The best source of information for gazebo plugins is typically the header file and/or the code itself.
In this case, the logic is as follows:

topic can be used to freely choose the topic.
Its value can be "specified_topic_name" but could as well be "specified_topic_name/my_subtopic_name", etc.

However, if you want to keep the default topic name structure (i.e. /model/{name_of_model}/cmd_vel) and only change its cmd_vel part, than you don't specify a value for topic, but instead a value for sub_topic.
Alternatively, you could specify a string "model/{name_of_model}/my_subtopic_name" as value for topic. But this is not always possible, as you do not necessarily always know the model name (e.g. when spawning multiple identical models from a script, with 'allow_renaming: true', then unique model names are generated upon spawn).

As you noticed, if topic is specified, then sub_topic is ignored. Which makes sense, given subtopic is irrelevant if topic is defined.


